# Proving that $\log(1-ei) = 1-i(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: complex-numbers

One thing that I know is $|ie|=e$ and $\log(z) = \ln|z| + i\arg(z)$, but I don't know how to calculate it because there is 1 there.

Comment: Well, you first have to calculate the absolute value of the argument, that is $\left|  1- ei\right|$

Comment: You could also just take $e$ to the power of each side, leaving $1-ei$ on one side, and $e^(1-i(\pi/2))$ on the other and go from there.

Comment: (I am not fond of mixing $\log$ and $\ln$. I was taught to use $\log$ for $\log_e$, while I presume that by $\log$ you are meaning $\log_{10}$?)

Comment: @user1729 from context it is apparent that $\ln$ is the real logarithm and $\log$ is the complex logarithm.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That makes sense. Incidentally, WolframAlpha claims that this is false, for a variety of bases of log.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I think that this identity is wrong too. But I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\ln(ei)=1-i\frac\pi2$?

Comment: Also incidentally, the now-deleted answer of @lurker seems to be mostly correct and shows that the identity is false (I think there is a small error, as $e^{i\pi/2}=\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)=-1\neq i$, but then you get $1+e=ei$ which is again a contradiction). I don't understand the downvote on it, or why it was deleted.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It's already the question from my book. And yeah I'm new in math stackexchange

Comment: @salomohutapea What does the question say *exactly*.

Comment: I meant $\ln(\color{red}-ei)=1-i\frac\pi2$

Comment: @user1729 the original question is Prove that log($1-ei$) = $1 - i(π/2)$. This such a bad queston I think.

Comment: @salomohutapea Is that *exactly* what it says? (For example, is it in a foreign language and this is your translation of it?) What I'm wondering is if the question says something like "Is it true that..." or even "Try and prove that..." (this second phrasing should be discouraged though!)

Comment: @user1729 - how did you get $cos(\pi/2) + i sin(\pi/2) = -1$? Isn't $cos(\pi/2) = 0$ and $sin(\pi/2) = 1$?

Comment: @lurker yup, it should be $1$ :-)

Comment: @user1729 yes that is exactly what it says. The question confused me at first, until I realize that it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that the identity is not true:

1. $\log(1-ei) = 1-i(\dfrac{\pi}{2}$)
2. $1-ei = e^{1-i(\dfrac{\pi}{2})}$
3. $1-ei = \dfrac{e}{e^\dfrac{i\pi}{2}} = \dfrac{e}{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)} = \dfrac{e}{i}$
4. $i+e = e$
5. $i = 0$

Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I believe that this is broadly correct, but you cannot take roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Instead, you should evaluate $e^{i\pi/2}$ using $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lurker

Comment: @user1729 so it has to be changed to polar form?

Comment: @user1729 thanks, I'll fix that.

Comment: @salomohutapea Yes. In general, roots are complicated in $\mathbb{C}$. For example, the equation $x^2=1$ has two distinct roots, $x^3=1$ has three distinct roots, and in general $x^n=1$ has $n$ distinct roots. Look up "roots of unity" for more details.

Comment: (4) isn't true because if $a=bi$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ then $a=0=b$.

Comment: @user1729 yeah that's pretty obvious. I should have left my "...need more coffee..." comment.

Comment: @lurker That's okay - I clearly need more coffee too!

Comment: (Incidentally, try not to use `\dfrac`. Just use `\frac`, which is more flexible. TeX will work out how to process `\frac`, while `\dfrac` is you imposing your opinions on TeX. For example, the way you wrote $\frac{e}{e^{i\pi/2}}$ looks out of place because of the `\dfrac`. It fits in better if you use `\frac`.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution guys, I really apreciate it.

Comment: @salomohutapea Noone said I was a guy.....

Comment: @user1729 hmm okay, thank you so much.

Comment: @salomohutapea You can upvote as well as accept answers. Upvoting shows appreciation and helps better answers to be more visible.

Comment: @user1729 thanks for the dfrac suggestion. I am new to TeX and I ran into it when I was not liking the tiny numerator/denominator TeX was giving me.

Comment: Its a pet peeve of mine. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12978/10513).

Comment: @user1729 I understand. I actually felt a little dirty using it. lol